# Reading a tab delimited Text file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to read a text file that is comprised of stock symbols and the associated company into a dictionary, each line in the text file has one symbol and company like

APPL  Apple

GOOG-Q  Google

Ultimately, I'm trying to have a searchbar that looks up the corresponding company based on the stock symbol (or vice versa).

So, what is the best way to approach this? read the entire file as a string then try to separate the items with fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n" or is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah that will work.  Get the lines by using `[... componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]` and then the fields within each line using `[... componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]` and then finally put the fields into a dictionary, keyed on the whatever field you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is often a good approach for parsing data.

You might want to pay attention to [the end-of-line character](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5A5A050A3019A573862575F30061D49B), depending on where the file comes from, it can be a linefeed (\n), carriage-return (\r), or both characters (\r\n).

Using NSScanner will make it easy for you to scan for lines, while ignoring the actual end-of-line character (see [[NSCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [newLineCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/newlineCharacterSet)]).

Comment: Thanks I will look into the NSscanner